# Refresh Jquery Dashboard on dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, dashboard

I created Jquery Dashboard near about 13 widget which load dynamically on button click event. Now I put One drop down list on the individual widget.

I am getting reference to create jquery dashboard: **"https://github.com/ModelN/sDashboard"**

**My issue is: When I change the value of drop down list then loaded widget is refresh, but I am not able to refresh that particular widget.**

Below is the code for add widget dynamically.

```
if (widgetId == "Id17") {
 openIRByProject();
$("#Dashboard").Dashboard("addWidget", {
widgetTitle: data[i].WidgetTitle,
widgetId: data[i].WidgetId,
widgetType: data[i].WidgetType,
widgetContent: dashboardData.OpenIRByProject
  });
}
```

Below is the code for initialize the widget and get data from SQL.

```
function openIRByProject() {

    dashboardData.OpenIRByProject = {

        "aaData": [[createDataOpenIRByProject(false)], [createDataOpenIRByProject(true)]],

        "aoColumns": [[{
            "sTitle": "IR #"
        },
        {
            "sTitle": "Description"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Occurences"
        },
         {
             "sTitle": "Project"
         },
          {
              "sTitle": "Action"
          },
           {
               "sTitle": "Severity"
           },
            {
                "sTitle": "Priority"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Res. associate"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Date Issued"
            }
        ],
        [{
            "sTitle": "IR #"
        },
        {
            "sTitle": "Description"
        },
         {
             "sTitle": "Occurences"
         },
          {
              "sTitle": "Action"
          }, ]
        ]
    };
}
```

From "createDataOpenIRByProject" method I am getting the data from database by AJAX call.

and when I change the drop down value then below code is call, but from this code I am getting latest data from database but my widget not getting refresh with new data.

```
function refreshWidget(obj, widgetId) {
    if (widgetId == "Id17") {        
        openIRByProject();
    }
}
```

Comment: the code which you are running on button click .just run same code for dropdown change event also..

Comment: I do the same but its not working.